# Why is waterfall so slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm using async module (see https://github.com/caolan/async) for Node.js and my question is... **Why is waterfall so slow?**

It takes about **4 seconds** to execute this piece of code...

```
App.post("/form", function(request, response) {

Async.waterfall([

  function(callback) {

    console.log("1.");
    callback(null, "some data");

  },

  function(data, callback) {

    console.log("2.");            
    callback(null, "some data");

  },

  function(data, callback) {

    console.log("3.");
    callback(null, "some data");              

  }

], function(error, document) {

  console.log("4.");            
  console.log("Done.");

  response.send(); // Takes 4 seconds

});

}
```

**Output**

```
1.
2.
// After 4 seconds
3.
4.
Done.
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: What is response? Also is that the real code? Because this executes immediately here.

Comment: I am using Node.js v0.3.2-pre, which version do you use?

Comment: I'm on 3.2-pre(5a87bd168d8fbeca7d48b9ddaa3b4e8a9336719c) too, but still the question is how does your real code look like?

Comment: @Ivo I just edited my question, this is how my code looks like. (Yes, I'm using Express.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just another Node.js Bug.

Using `process.nextTick` inside another `process.nextTick` during a pending `http.ServerResponse` is broken.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var now = new Date();
    process.nextTick(function() {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            console.log(new Date() - now);
            res.writeHead({});
            res.end('foooooo');
        });
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

This takes an eternity, `async.js` calls the callbacks from inside the other callbacks which were called via `process.nextTick` which then results in the above bug being triggered.

**Quick fix:** In `async.js` line `63` modifiy `async.nextTick` to only use `setTimeout`.

**Bug:** I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/ry/node/issues/issue/509) on this.